# Не работает CMake Qt macOS

Tags: qt, macos, cmake

Установил `Qt 5.9.2` с `Qt Creator 4.4.1` создаю проект "Проект без Qt" -> "Приложение на языке C++" -> ... -> Система сборки: CMake

После того как Qt все прогрузит в папке проекта отображается только `CMakeList.txt` (в самой папке лежит также `main.cpp` и `CMakeList.txt.user`) добавить файлы нельзя, запустить  проект тоже нельзя, консоль сборки пустая.

Подскажите, как это исправить.

[image: Контекстное меню проекта]
[image: Панель запуска]
[image: Проект CMake Qt macOS]

Comment: Нажмите на пункт меню `Запустить CMake`. После этого должно все появится. А добавлять файлы нужно в CMakeLists.txt вручную.

Comment: @Anton, к сожалению не помогает, по нажатию на "Запустить CMake" ничего не происходит